# How to remove readonly property in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to remove `readonly` property from one `Input tag` via selenium in java. I'm using the below code to remove **readonly** property and I'm accessing Input tag via xpath:

```
WebElement InTag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='7']//input[@id='arid7']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly','readonly')",InTag);
```

But it throws the below error :

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: arguments[0] is undefined
```

Comment: Maybe because you tried use WE like an array but it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly','readonly')",InTag);
```

To this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments.removeAttribute('readonly','readonly')",InTag);
```

Whatever `arguments` is, it is not an array or it is an empty array.